# Dagger cycle dependency issue for ViewModelFactory and AndroidInjection

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger

I want to understand why I have dagger cycle dependency here:

```
class MachineFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory

    private lateinit var viewModel: MachinesViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MachinesViewModel::class.java)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_machines, container, false)
    }
```

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    dependencies = [],
    modules = [
        AppModule::class,
        TestViewModelModule::class,
        InjectorModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(subject: AppApplication)
```

```
public abstract class TestViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    public abstract ViewModelFactory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);

    /*
        you have to explicitly define ViewModel instead of concrete
        implementation to avoid cycle dependency error
    */
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MachinesViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindMachinesViewModel(MachinesViewModel vm);
}
```

```
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> viewModels;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> viewModels) {
        this.viewModels = viewModels;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<ViewModel> viewModelProvider = viewModels.get(modelClass);

        if (viewModelProvider == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("model class " + modelClass + " not found");
        }

        return (T) viewModelProvider.get();
    }

}
```

However when I define the same injection field in `MainActivity`, cycle dependency disappear:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory

    private lateinit var viewModel: MachinesViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /* start destination in navigation.xml defines entry point */

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MachinesViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

I already have solved this issue by adding `@Named("machine-vm-factory")` annotation, but the root cause is unclear for me. I will appreciate your thoughts on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line in `TestViewModelModule`:

```
@Binds
public abstract ViewModelFactory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
```

Here you're asking Dagger to give you a `ViewModelFactory` whenever anyone requests a `ViewModelFactory`, and since `@Binds` has a higher priority than `@Inject`, Dagger doesn't really know how to construct a `ViewModelFactory`, hence the cycle.

Adding qualifier changes the key:

```
@Binds
@Named("machine-vm-factory")
public abstract ViewModelFactory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
```

This means that when anyone is asking for a `@Named("machine-vm-factory") ViewModelFactory`, Dagger will give us a `ViewModelFactory` using the `@Inject` annotated constructor, so the cycle is gone.

See https://dagger.dev/semantics/#keys

Comment: Thank you. The worked ```@Named``` was clear for me, the issue which is not clear a root cause of this cycle dependency. I have only one ```ViewModelFactory```, nothing more extends it or its interface. ```Dagger``` should not have any issues to find it and supply into the place where is injected. An another hand ```@Named``` annotation is usually used to distinguish two different instances of the same interface, and by unclear reason it solves this cyclic dependency. ```ViewModelFactory``` should be a single instance class, there is no more classes with the same interface. Is not it?

Comment: Let me try another way. In order to inject any type, Dagger needs to know how to inject all of its dependencies. And in your bind method you put `ViewModelFactory` in the return type as well as in the parameter type, which is telling Dagger `ViewModelFactory` depends on `ViewModelFactory`. This is a cycle because something depends on itself. And when you put `@Named` on the bind method it changes the key. It then becomes `@Named(...) ViewModelFactory` depends on `ViewModelFactory`. This is not a cycle because something depends on something else.